# Oracle Apex unable to align page items with checkbox

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a modal dialog with Theme as page moda as modal dialog.

It has 5 items where there'sone checkbox and rest 4 are text boxes appearing conditionally.

So at one time there would be only one item showing.

Currently Modal dialog width is 500.

Even when the check box and other items have Start new row turned off and in the layout in app builder they seem in same row..

When app is run they all come in separate rows.

```
Checkbox

Item_1
```

I tried increasing width but that stretches dialog, and the checkbox and item appear something like this.

```
Checkbox    
        Item_1
```

Due to restrictions i cannot show this in demo app.
Please advise if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at Layout's properties that are related to columns:

- `column` says in which of **12** columns (every page, every region is split into 12 columns) will that item be positioned
- `column span` says how many columns (out of 12) will that item occupy
- `label column span` says how many columns will item's **label** take

[image]

I don't know which values you'll use here, but - play with it, set them to various values to get the idea of what you can do with it, and then find a combination which will suit your needs.